# Phalcon router sends the wrong parameters

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-routing

I have a problem with my router in Phalcon.
I have an action in my controller which ether takes a date parameter or not.
So when I access an URL: http://example.com/sl/slots/index/2017-06-27
everything works ok.
But when I go to: http://example.com/sl/slots/index
I get the following error:

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (sl) at position
>   0 (s): The timezone could not be found in the database.

So the router actually takes the "sl" in the beginning as a parameter.

My router for this kind of url is set like this:

```
$router->add(
    "/{language:[a-z]{2}}/:controller/:action",
    array(
        "controller" => 2,
        "action"     => 3
    )
);
```

Btw it does the same withut the index: http://example.com/sl/slots

Oh and my slots index action looks like this:

```
public function indexAction($currentDate = false){ //code }
```

So the $currentDate is set to "sl" when I call the action without a parameter

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @Juri's answer.. I prefer to keep my Actions empty or as slim as possible. Imagine if you have 3-4 parameters in the Route, you will end up with something like:

```
public function indexAction($param1 = false, $param2 = false, $param3 = false....)
```

Here is how I prefer to handle Route parameters:

```
public function indexAction()
{
  // All parameters
  print_r($this->dispatcher->getParams());

  // Accessing specific Named parameters
  $this->dispatcher->getParam('id');
  $this->dispatcher->getParam('language');

  // Accessing specific Non-named parameters
  $this->dispatcher->getParam(0);
  $this->dispatcher->getParam(1);
  ...
}
```

Comment: This makes it more difficult to immediately see at a glance what parameters the action accepts.  I use action parameters all the time as it helps me interpret what the action url should look like.

Comment: Sounds reasonable with low amount of parameters. If you like to have such info in controller, maybe Router Annotations can be handy? https://olddocs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.0/reference/routing.html#annotations-router

Comment: What are you gaining then?  Interested in discussion, not an argument.  With all due respect, what gain is there to not having action parameters?  All I'm seeing is negatives.

Comment: Never ever wanted to sound like arguing :) Just shared alternative with Annotations to action parameters in the method. *Personally* I don't like having actions with many parameters like `public function blogPostAction($language, $category, $year, $month, $day, $id, $slug)`, what if we have to add default values? But maybe you could be right... it doesn't hurt that much after all :)

Comment: Didn't think you were argumentative, just wanted to ensure I didn't sound argumentative too ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well you need to add language in first argument of action too. Then it should work.